# How to scale my svg internal elements to fit the window in width and height

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

please check this demo .

https://codepen.io/wasiabbas/pen/JQmXmE

when curly braces if coming from left i need to make it fit in height and when it rotates then i need to fit the curly braces in window width. how can i do it?

```
var winWidth = window.innerWidth,
        winHeight = window.innerHeight;

    const bracesContainer = document.querySelector('.braces-container');
    const braces = document.getElementById('braces');
    const bracesbg = document.getElementById('bracesbg');
    const leftbraces = document.getElementById('leftcb');
    const topbraces = document.getElementById('topcb');

    function loadAnimation(){

        $(braces).css({
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            width: winWidth,
            height: winHeight
        });

        TweenMax.to(braces, 0.9, {
            right:0
        });

        TweenMax.to(leftbraces, 0.9, {
            opacity: 0,
            rotation: -90,
            y: '60%',
            x: '10%',
            transformOrigin: 'center center',
            delay: .5
        });


        TweenMax.to(topbraces, 1.2, {
            opacity:1,
            delay: 1
        });

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadAnimation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet with a simple solution (using D3.js):

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));

svg.select('path')
 .transition()
    .delay(500)
 .duration(1000)
 .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${width}) rotate(-90) scale(${width/height})`)
```

```css
svg {
 background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width='250' height='200'>
<path d='M 0,0 H 100 Q 125,0 125,25 V 75 Q 125,100 150,100 
Q 125,100 125,125 V 175 Q 125,200 100,200 H 0 z' fill='#fff' />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, tried it with your way, its working but somehow not fully responsive. the internal path is not streching to window size. please check here.

https://codepen.io/wasiabbas/pen/gNBmLP

Thanks

Comment: Remove **width:100%;height:100%;** from your svg's CSS. The size of SVG should be given explicitly by width and height attributes: **<svg width="1024" height="768">**

Comment: removed. but now its going larger than window. https://codepen.io/wasiabbas/pen/gNBmLP

Comment: Set SVG width/height according to its container. Something like this: `container.addEventListener('resize', () => {svg.attr('width', container.clientWidth).attr('height', container.clientHeight)});`

Comment: setting viewBox="0 0 250 156" preserveAspectRatio="none" with width height attributes makes it scale to fit the window. please check here. https://codepen.io/wasiabbas/pen/gNBmLP , after lots of hardwork its working now. but shapes getting distorted.

Comment: viewBox and preserveAspectRatio will distort or limit the SVG content, I recommend to omit them. You need to set the SVG actual width and height as of the parent DIV and resize SVG when DIV is resized by setting SVG's width and height attributes explicitly! Good luck. If you find my answer useful, please upvote :)